# How to exclude mock files from Code Coverage Istanbul Reporter

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a question regarding Istanbul Reporter used for reporting my unit testing coverage in my angular 6 application.

My problem is: when the coverage is rendered, I see the mocks in the tested files list and obviously the mocks aren't tested, which gives me wrong coverage stats.

This is my karma.conf file setup by a colleague and I'd like to know if you have any idea on how to exclude those mock files.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'local'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I saw on StackOverflow that it might be done by adding an exclude in the tsconfig.spec.json but even by re-running the code coverage, it still includes them.

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "/**/*mock*.ts"
  ]
}
```

My mock files are inside **tests**/mocks folder in every module/feature and are called "mock-whatevertheymock.ts"

The command to run it is

```
test:wc-dogs": "ng test --project=wc-dogs--code-coverage
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thank you everyone, solution was to add the `codeCoverageExclude` option in angular.json

```
   "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "projects/wc-claims/src/test.ts",
                "polyfills": "projects/wc-claims/src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "projects/wc-claims/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "karmaConfig": "projects/wc-claims/karma.conf.js",
                "styles": [
                  "projects/wc-claims/src/styles.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [],
                "assets": [
                  "projects/wc-claims/src/favicon.ico",
                  "projects/wc-claims/src/assets"
                ],
                "codeCoverageExclude": [
                    "/**/*mock*.ts"
                ]
              }
            },
```

Comment: I search high and low for this.

Comment: it somehow didn't work for some files when I add a directory under codeCoverageExclude which was also the same directory I provided in it

Comment: just make sure to alway use the wildcard `**` and `*`.

For folders excluding with `src/testing` does not work, you must use `src/testing/**`

For files `*.mock.ts` does not work, you must use `**/*.mock.ts`

Answer (score 0):

You should add exclude to karma config.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'local'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    exclude: ["/**/*mock*.ts"],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately :/ they still appear in the coverage results

Comment: ts files are in your mock folder right ? it is mock/test.ts ??

Comment: For example let's say Dogs folder
``
- Dog
-- dog.service.ts
-- dog.component.ts
-- dog.component.html
-- __tests__
--- dog.component.spec.ts
--- mocks
---- mock-dog.service.ts
``

Comment: @Dinosan0908 in that case this regex is incorrect ["/**/*mock*.ts"] it should be ["/**/mock/*.ts"]. Try updating it because I am already excluding files from test coverage.

Comment: Ok I found something on another answer, I'll post it as answer of my question, thanks for help sir !

Comment: I tested the glob with my file structure and the one I provided work, it was just in the wrong spot :)